# Removing certain links in admin header bar added by plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have instaled several plugins and they tend to add links on the admin bar that is

I have ultimate affiliate pro and it has added new and referral affiliate and other plugins like ithemes security has a link on the admin bar such that now my admin bar looks mesed up like in the image below

[image]

How can i edit this is there a plugin which can remove certain links on the admin dashboard bar without having to disable the plugins

I have tried:

```
checking on the screen options but there is no way to uncheck links
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of how you can remove the unwanted links from admin_bar.

```
function remove_admin_bar_links() {
    global $wp_admin_bar;
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wporg');            // Remove the WordPress.org link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('documentation');    // Remove the WordPress documentation link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('support-forums');   // Remove the support forums link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('feedback');         // Remove the feedback link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('w3tc');             // If you use w3 total cache remove the performance link
    $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('my-account');       // Remove the user details tab
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'remove_admin_bar_links' );
```

You need to check the menu name and add it to the function call via add_action.